# Compare 2 Lists of numbers in LINQ Method Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-method-syntax

I have 2 lists of numbers.

```
public int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4 };
public int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5 };
```

I need output like below

## Expected Result

```
0 is less than 1
0 is less than 3
0 is less than 5

2 is less than 3
2 is less than 5

4 is less than 5
```

How is it possible through `LINQ` method syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Method syntax:

```
var result = numbersA.SelectMany(c => numbersB, (c, o) => new { c, o })
                     .Where(d => d.c < d.o)
                     .Select(v=>  v.c + "is less than"+ v.o);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers with explanation. Thanks akbari

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I ran some benchmarking comparing your solution and mine. Using source arrays of 1000 size and running 100 consecutive tests, my solution averages 0.272 seconds and yours averages 0.351 seconds.

Comment: what about for loops?

Answer (score 1):

**At times, verbosity take precedence over brevity as it is clearer and easier to read in most situation, although maybe a bit longer to type.**

There is no direct way to achieve what you want as you use Array instead of List (List has [`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx))

But if you want with Arrays I suggest using [`Array.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int[] numbersA = new int[] { 0, 2, 4 };
int[] numbersB = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };

Array.ForEach(numbersA, x =>
{
    Array.ForEach(numbersB, y =>
    {
        if (x < y)
            Console.WriteLine(x + " is less than " + y);
    });
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
});
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: `ForEach` isn't LINQ. It's a `List` method.

Comment: If you're going for the "verbosity is better than brevity for the sake of clarity" argument, you might as well just use a regular `for` or `foreach` instead of `Array.ForEach`. They're both faster, about the same amount of verbose, and are far clearer in their intent.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is nothing more than useless business logic, it looks funny to have a try. My solution is `List.Foreach` rather than `Linq`, but it is in only one statement.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numsA = { 0, 2, 4 };
        int[] numsB = { 1, 3, 5 };
        numsA.ToList().ForEach((a) =>
        {
            numsB.Where(b => b > a).ToList()
            .ForEach((x) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}>{1}", a, x);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: `ForEach` isn't LINQ. It's a method of `List`.

Comment: OP wants a LINQ solution, and `ForEach` isn't LINQ. Therefore, this isn't a solution to his question.

Comment: I think he just want something that looks elegant and one liner enough. Your  answer is the best though. S.Akbari is answering with linq but the OP is saying no, don't you think him funny?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4 };
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5 };

var result = numbersA.Select(a => numbersB.Where(b => a < b)
                                          .Select(b => a + " is less than " + b))
                     .SelectMany(arr => arr)
                     .ToArray();
```